# What's meaning of 担当さん

Tags: translation, meaning

> なんと担当さんがその辺に落ちてた枝や石を使って実際に作ってくれました

I can't finish the translation due I can't understand the 担当さん. At first time, somebody said me that it's name. But it's not name, right? 
I was told that this occupation. But I'm not sure in it. And now I don't know how to translate it. Help me, please! And thanks for your help!

Comment: Related question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/when-to-use-%E3%81%95%E3%82%93-after-an-occupation

Answer (score 5):

> 「(Name of profession or role one is in charge of) + さん」

is a very common way of addressing and referring to people in Japanese.

「[担当]{たんとう}」 is a person who has been put in charge of a task, and s/he works with/for you.  You may address or refer to him/her as 「担当さん」.

Translating 「担当さん」, however, would be a little difficult because this particular method of calling people might not be common in another culture.

What does this person do in your story/context/situation?  If there is a name for his/her job, you might want to use it - "my maid", "my butler", "my hair stylist", etc.

If it is just a role instead of a profession, you could just use "***the person/guy/lady, etc. in charge***".

Answer (score 4):

'担当' is a noun to mean 'to take charge of sth.' 'さん’ is an honorific suffix like Mr. and Ms. as you know. "担当さん" is a vocative to mean "Mr./Ms. someone in charge of business."

It's widely used when the name, title and position of a person who handles business, request, and procedure of a client, customer, and resident in an organization e.g. companies, shops, hospitals, and government offices) are unavailable.

When you call a branch office of the municipal office to complain about dangerous pitfalls on the pavement in front of your house, and you don't know whom in the office to talk to, you ask "Can I talk to 担当さん, or 係りの人?" instead of calling Mr. John Doe, 課長さん - Section manager, and complaint officer.