# Meaning of My担当氏

Tags: meaning, words

I learnt from [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34442/17797) that 担当さん is a common Japanese expression to address someone working with/for you. Does the presence of `My` and `氏` add a more specific meaning? The context is a letter from a mangaka to her fans:

> My担当氏とお誕生日が近いという事で、２人でバースデイパーティーを開きました✨

Considering they are having a party alone and that she later says she received a heart-shaped cake as a present, it could be his boyfriend, but I don't think that's the meaning of My担当氏. Since the letter was handwritten, [here's the original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAFC6.jpg) to check if I read the characters right. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

氏 is generally more formal (and thus less friendly) than さん, but in this case I don't feel she chose 氏 to show her respect or psychological distance. 氏 is just another common name suffix in this situation. This may or may not be related, but stereotyped hardcore otaku address everyone using 氏 and it actually is a friendly yet respectful suffix like くん/さん to them.

The use of *My* is hard to explain since it's not standard nor common at all. Maybe she just wanted to decorate 担当さん with *My* to make it a bit more eccentric, cute, or whatever. It does not alter the basic meaning of the sentence.

Comment: So, without more context it is not possible to know who My担当氏 refers to (her boss, a colleague, etc.), right?

Comment: Ah, when a manga-ka calls someone 担当, It's almost certainly a corresponding editorial staff at the publisher. Manga-ka usually work at their home, and 担当者 collect and check manuscripts, and often even give advices to them.

Comment: A typical 担当者 is [this](http://bakuman.wikia.com/wiki/Akira_Hattori). A 担当者 is assigned to each manga-ka and they usually work as a pair thereafter. They usually call each other with their names, but 担当者's names are often hidden in books.

Comment: Oh, so it's an editor in this case! Thank you for the information!